# Having trouble with a simple linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to understand linked lists. I created this code which is supposed to give me experience with linked lists. When I run this code I get 0, though the output should be 10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0. Could someone help me figure this out?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int value;
    struct node *next;
}node;

node * addnode (node *ptr, int value);

void traverse(node *ptr);

int main (void)
{
    int i;
    node *ptr,*root;
    root=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    ptr=root;
    root->value=0;
    root->next=0;
    for(i=1;i>10;i++)
        ptr=addnode(ptr,i);
    traverse(ptr);
    return(0);
}

void traverse(node *ptr)
{
    printf("%d\n",ptr->value);
    if(ptr->next) /*assuming that the pointer to the next node is initialized to NULL, so if its NULL then the if codeblock won't execute*/
        traverse(ptr->next);
}

node * addnode (node *ptr, int value)
{
    node *newnode;
    newnode=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    newnode->value=value;
    newnode->next=ptr;
    return(newnode);
}
```

Comment: did you step through it with a debugger?

Comment: You should change `traverse(ptr);` in main to `traverse(root);`. You've left `prt` at the last node. To output the whole linked list, start at the head/root.

Comment: Also, I don't think that your for-loop is correct.  Your i variable is never greater than 10, therefore, the body of your loop won't execute.

Comment: also this is a very odd list. The next pointer points to the previous element. Traditional linked lists add things at the end

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code:

1. Ideally, you would do `traverse(root)` instead of `traverse(ptr)`.
2. You are adding nodes at the beginning of your linked list, when you should add them on the end of the list.

You can do it like this ([source](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/103/LinkedListBasics.pdf)):

```
void Push(struct node** headRef, int newData) {
    struct node* new_node =
        (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new_node->data = newData;
    new_node->next = *headRef;
    *headRef = new_node;

}
```

which in your case would look like:

```
void addnode(struct node** headRef, int newData) {
    struct node* new_node =
        (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new_node->value = newData;
    new_node->next = *headRef;
    *headRef = new_node;

}
```

Then you add nodes like this: `addnode(&root, some_value);`